# split columns into multiple columns

Tags: r, string, dataframe, split

i have been struggled with how to split multiple columns into multiple columns using R but with no result, i have tried many tricks on Stackoverflow and it doesn't work. here is my probleme :

```
reactions__001 reactions__002 reactions__003
25 Like        23 Love                
15 Like        5 Love         3 Haha                          
20 Haha        3 Sad          2 Angry
```

now what i am looking for is to split this data frame like this one

```
Like Love Haha Sad Angry
25   23   0    0   0      
15   5    3    0   0                         
0    0    20   3   2
```

i have tried the `str_split_fixed(df$reactions__001, " ", 2)`   but it gives me something like :

```
 [26,] "1"  "Angry"
 [27,] "3"  "Like" 
 [28,] "0"  ""     
 [29,] ""   ""     
 [30,] "1"  "Like" 
 [31,] "10" "Like"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
xx$id = 1:nrow(xx)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
xxlong = gather(xx, key = "key", value = "value",-id)
xxlong = separate(xxlong, value, into = c("num", "attr"))
xxlong %>% na.omit %>% select(-key) %>%
    spread(key = attr, value = num, fill = 0)
#   id Angry Haha Like Love Sad
# 1  1     0    0   25   23   0
# 2  2     0    3   15    5   0
# 3  3     2   20    0    0   3
```

I'll leave the reordering of the columns to you.

---

Using this data:

```
xx = read.table(text = "reactions__001 reactions__002 reactions__003
'25 Like'        '23 Love'                
'15 Like'        '5 Love'         '3 Haha'                          
'20 Haha'        '3 Sad'          '2 Angry'  ", header = T, fill = T)
```

Comment: Why not pipe all of them together?

Comment: I think it will help OP learn what each command does separately. Offers opportunities to adjust and debug. Anyone can stick them together once they understand what's going on - but newbies often are too shy about taking things apart.

Comment: @Gregor what if i  had a data frame, like this one `"review","reactions__001","reactions__002","reactions__003","username","rating","date"` do i need to change something in the code above ?

Comment: @Gregor Yea, it just seems inconsistent to me that you're piping some but not all functions. Good point with the educational purpose. Better explain the steps then, if your intend is to educate beginners.

Comment: Thank you so much @Gregor you saved my day